# EXCEL: First cell within a numerical range in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello beautiful people,

Preamble:
I have a pipe filled with a gas mixture that separates over time. I'm doing the simulation in Excel.
I did the whole separation dynamics, and now I have a distribution inside the "pipe".
I would like to know in which position of the pipe one of the components starts to accumulate.
So, the calculation ends with a small "Position-in-the-pipe vs. Elements" matrix, with normalized values between 0 and 1 (percentage), filled with a normal distribution, etc.
At first, I wanted to search for the first non-0 value in the column containing the percentage of the gas I'm interested in, but the normal distribution fills almost all the cells with non-0s (ex- 1,1*E-171), which is great because I need it to be rather accurate but made my attempts useless.

[image: snapshot of the file with the values matrix and the #NA cell highlighted]

Question:
So now I'm searching for the first (and later also the last) cell in the range 0,005 and 0,01 in the column of the element I'm interested in.
I've tried now for about 3 hours combinations of INDEX, MATCH, and LOOKUP, either built by me or scraped off here. Each time I get close to promising formulas, I always get the #NA error, which is impossible because I see the numbers I use as search criteria.
Does any of you have any idea?
I'm kinda losing it over here.

Comment: "Each time I get close to promising formulas, I always get the #NA error", please post the formula you're using (the most promising one), as there can be several things causing the #NA-error

Comment: Also please share which Excel version you're using. Office 365?

Comment: Please also note that many of the gas columns don't contain a value between your given filter range. What do you expect to get for `KR80` and in case of `KR82`, would you list `0,01`, which is the last value, but the only value meeting the conditions.

Comment: Thanks everybody, for the replies!

@tnavidi, the one that looked best to me is:
=INDEX(AA41:AA141;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(AA41:AA141<>0;);0))
This works, but as I said, it always gives me the first cell because of the very long tail of the normal distribution, but I do not know how to modify it without falling into the #NA.

Comment: @P.b Office Home and Business 2019 (last update):
Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO (Version 2309 Build 16.0.16827.20014) 64 Bit 
The table is 100 cells long, all going eventually as high as 1.

Comment: So would this not work? `=INDEX(AA41:AA141;MATCH(1;(AA41:AA141>0,005)*(AA41:AA141<0,01);0))` using `ctrl+shift+enter` to enter as array formula

Comment: it returns #VALUE.
if I search in the step-by-step evaluation, the #VALUE begins immediately with the AA41:AA141, as if the array was not an acceptable input?

Answer (score 2):

The two formulas are in the cells above each

IMPORTANT! This is an array formula after type it in the cell press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

For first

```
=MATCH(1;IF((D$1:D$9>B1)*(D$1:D$9<B2)=1;1;0);0)
```

For last

```
=MAX((D$1:D$9>B1)*(D$1:D$9<B2)*ROW(D$1:D$9))
```

the result in the cell is the row number in the column range

This is the example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Sadly, your formula also results in #NA.
(my company is German so I have to work in german)
here's the adapted formula: 
{=VERGLEICH(1;WENN((AA$41:AA$141>L17)*(AA$41:AA$141<L16)=1;1;0);0)}
and still, it tells me there are no values between the selected range (0,05 and 0,1)

Comment: Depends on local setup the `;`  (semicolon) or the `,`  (comma) has to be used for separator. Does L16 is max value and L17 is Min value

Comment: For which gas did you try and is L17 = 0,05 and L16 = 0,1? @Brun0

Comment: @Blackcat, local set-up semicolon, but already taking that in consideration, thank for the reminder thou

Comment: @Notus_Panda,
The actual values can be inferred in the plot above, which practically is the plot of the matrix. I`m searching for the 85(red line in the plot), but that's only partially relevant. All the columns have values ranging from 0 to 1, besides Ne Ar and O2, which still go between 0 and 0.25, and for the lowest case, Kr 78 which is practically non-existent in the system.

Comment: I was just asking in case you swapped the minimum and maximum values by accident since you'd assume the lowest value would be in L16 not L17. Making sure we're covering everything possible here. I just tested Black Cat's answer with 87 rows with varying values between 0 - 1 and descending again from there to 0 like you'd have it and it works.

Comment: If all parameters are correct and still #N/A the result, that means that there is no value within the limits. Furtherly the two limits are not included in the test. If they needed ,change  `>` to `>=` and `<` to `<=` in the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `XMATCH` on your version of excel, then you can use -1 to reverse the search.

Here's the formula I have so far to get the first/last number. The advantage is that it uses only one comparison.

```
=XMATCH(TRUE;ABS(J1:J17-((B2+B1)/2))<=ABS((B1-B2)/2);0;1)
=XMATCH(TRUE;ABS(J1:J17-((B2+B1)/2))<=ABS((B1-B2)/2);0;-1)
```

the boundry values are in B1 and B2. The input is in J1:J17

[image]

Further you can use XLOOKUP for getting the corresponding value from the Rohr column:

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE;ABS(J1:J17-(($B$2+$B$1)/2))<=ABS(($B$1-$B$2)/2);$I1:$I17;"no";0;1)
=XLOOKUP(TRUE;ABS(J1:J17-(($B$2+$B$1)/2))<=ABS(($B$1-$B$2)/2);$I1:$I17;"no";0;-1)
```

I have used $I1:$I17 as the Rohr column. I also added the `$`s to make it easier to drag-copy to the right

[image]

Here is an alternative that doesn't use `XLOOKUP`:

```
=MIN(IFNA(IF(ABS(J1:J17-((B2+B1)/2))<=ABS((B1-B2)/2);1;NA())*I1:I17;10000))
=MAX(IF(ABS(J1:J17-((B2+B1)/2))<=ABS((B1-B2)/2);1;0)*I1:I17)
```

I'm not sure if it will be correct on your version of excel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that would have been perfect!
obviously, my version doesn't support XMATCH :-D

Comment: Added a formula that doesn't use xmatch, however, I'm not sure if it will work on your version

Comment: it returns #VALUES.
I can't fathom what the hell is happening.
For whatever reason it is telling me that the evaluation of the AA41:AA141 fails to return a value

Comment: You might need to use ctrl-enter after entering the formula as it is an array there.

Comment: i actually think there is some messed-up set up in my local options, I have tried many thing that should work, and upon debugging it looks like excel has having problem recognizing the array as numbers

Comment: did you try using the *ctrl-enter*? this tells excel that you're using arrays in the formula, and the result is that there are brackets around the formula like this: `{=MAX(IF(ABS(J1:J17-((B2+B1)/2))<=ABS((B1-B2)/2);1;0)*I1:I17)}` (ps. you can't type in the brackets manually)

Answer (score 0):

Quick update:
The values of the whole matrix are summarized in the plot above.
The data I'm interested in are the red ones for Kr-85.

This formula:

```
=INDEX(AA41:AA141;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(AA41:AA141>=0,01;);0))
```

finds the right value for the cutoff.
But if I want to know to which position on the pipe it corresponds (purple right column in the snapshot) (with a slookup),

```
=SLOOKUP(INDEX(AA41:AA141;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(AA41:AA141>=0,01;);0)); (P41:AA141);1;)
```

I go back to the #NA.

Additionally, if I try to find the other cutoff by changing the criteria from different to 0 to the majority of the signal (total signal value 17,21) it goes again to either #VALUE or #NA

```
=INDEX(AA41:AA141;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(SUM(AA41:AA141)>=17,2;);0))
```

#VALUE

or

```
=INDEX(AA41:AA141;VERGLEICH(WAHR;INDEX(AA41:AA141>=17,2;);0))
```

#NA

P.S.
Sadly, the software is set up in German, so I have to translate all the function names. Typos in the functions are most likely due to my translations, in the software, I use autocomplete to avoid making these mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

For the upper limit (first match):

```
=INDEX(P41:P141; MATCH(INDEX(AA41:AA141;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(AA41:AA141>=0,01;);0)); AA41:AA141; 0))
```

For the lower limit (last match):

```
{=INDEX(P41:P141;MATCH(INDEX(AA41:AA141;MAX(IF((AA41:AA141>0,0000001)*(AA41:AA141<=0,05);ROW(AA41:AA141)-MIN(ROW(AA41:AA141))+1))); AA41:AA141; 0))
```

I have the feeling that this is kinda of a brute force approach, but as long as it works...

Thanks anybody for the very useful tips!